# Make querySelector only target THIS element that is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that encompasses a checkbox, I want to only have the querySelector target the child element of THIS clicked element. As of right now, if I click the one below, it will trigger the click on the checkbox above. How can I do this?
**HTML**

```
<div class="message-checkbox-container" style="height: 47px;" onclick="triggerCheck()">
     <input class="message-checkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="message-checkbox-container" style="height: 47px;" onclick="triggerCheck()">
     <input class="message-checkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function triggerCheck(){
document.querySelector('.message-checkbox').click();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the event listener using `addEventListener` instead - inline handlers have [way too many problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) to be worth using in a modern codebase. To attach the listener, select `.message-checkbox-container` elements, and you can use the closure over each element to refer to its first child, the input, inside the listener:

```js
for (const container of document.querySelectorAll('.message-checkbox-container')) {
  container.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.children[0].click();
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="message-checkbox-container" style="height: 47px;">container
     <input class="message-checkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="message-checkbox-container" style="height: 47px;">container
     <input class="message-checkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Not that you should do this, but you can reference `this` inside an inline handler to get a reference to the element the handler is attached to - you can pass that to the function and have the function call `querySelector` (or `.children[0]`) on it:

```js
function triggerCheck(elm) {
  elm.querySelector('.message-checkbox').click();
}
```

```html
<div class="message-checkbox-container" style="height: 47px;" onclick="triggerCheck(this)">container
  <input class="message-checkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="message-checkbox-container" style="height: 47px;" onclick="triggerCheck(this)">container
  <input class="message-checkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

You might consider using a `<label>` instead of a `<div>`, that way the checkbox will be toggled automatically when the label is clicked, no Javascript necessary:

```css
.message-checkbox-container {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label class="message-checkbox-container" style="height: 47px;">container
  <input class="message-checkbox" type="checkbox">
</label>
<label class="message-checkbox-container" style="height: 47px;">container
  <input class="message-checkbox" type="checkbox">
</label>
```